# An understanding trouble with \framebox

Tags: macros, boxes

I'm reading [More Math Into LaTeX](https://www.springer.com/cn/book/9780387688527#otherversion=9780387322896), and it introduces the command of `\framebox` at section 3.9.2 on page 91-92. There are the two following code examples which show different output:

```
\framebox{\makebox[\totalheight]{1}}
\framebox[\totalheight]{1}
```

The book explains as follows:

> Indeed, `\totalheight` is the height of 1, which becomes the width of the box. The total height of the box, however, is the height of the character 1 to which you have to add twice the `\fboxsep`, the separation between the contents of the box and the frame, defined as 3 points, and twice the `\fboxrule`, the width of the line, or rule, defined as 0.4 points. These lengths are in general also added to the width of the box, but not in this case, **because we forced the width to equal the height of the character**.

Then how should I understand the last sentences and the totally different output? Hope someone could give me a hand.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Could you perhaps indicate which explanation is not clear to you? To me this explanation seems good to me, (And sorry, I cannot give a hand, I only have claws. ;-)

Comment: @marmot From the previous parts of the book, it says `\totalheight = \height + \depth`, but for `\framebox[\totalheight]{1}` the explanation seems show `totalheight = \height + 2\fboxsep + 2\fboxrule`, so it should be wilder than that of `\framebox{\makebox[\totalheight]{1}}`, and the last sentences make confusion of me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox\CBox
\begin{document}

\sbox\CBox{g}
\the\wd\CBox | \the\ht\CBox+\the\dp\CBox

\framebox{\makebox[\totalheight]{g}}
\framebox[\totalheight]{g}
\framebox[\width]{g}
\framebox[\the\dimexpr\ht\CBox+\dp\CBox]{g}

\sbox\CBox{\framebox[\totalheight]{g}}
\the\wd\CBox | \the\ht\CBox+\the\dp\CBox

\end{document}
```

[image]

A g has a width of 5pt, a height of 4.53pt and a depth of 2.05pt, which is 
a total height of 6.5899pt. With `\framebox[\totalheight]{g}` we get a width
of the box of 6.5899pt-0.8pt=5.711pt (the line width of the frame is subtracted
from the box! 5.711pt is nearly the same as the natural width of the box and 
`\totalheight` minus two times the line width makes no real difference.

Saving all in a box we get the width of 6.5899 (the line width is now 
part of the box), a height of 7.93pt which is the old height of the g plus 
`\fboxsep` (3pt) and `\fboxrule` (0.4pt). 
And the depth is the old value, plus also the `\fboxsep` and `\fboxrule`.

Comment: Thanks for your patient answer!  I think I understand now and I need to give a correction to your answer. In the output of your code, the left/right border of the output of `\framebox[\width]{g}` is tangent to g, so the width of box line seems not included in the `\width`. To give my summary of my understanding, `\makebox` functions as modification of the box dimension and  `\framebox` functions as `\makebox` but padds more with `\fboxsep` and `\fboxrule`. And in the command option parameter field, the dimension parameter is set according to the dimension of the mandatory box content.